# Segmentation fault when parsing command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am getting a segmentation fault I am having trouble isolating the source of the fault.  I believe that for some reason argv and argc are not getting values, but I cannot figure out why.

Here is the first part of my code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int i;
int numArrays = 0;
int test = 0;
int opt = 0;

printf ("Parsing....\n");  // This line gets printed
printf(argv);    // this one doesn't even if being flushed immediately after
printf(argc);    // when the previous line is deleted, this line also won't print
fflush(stdout); 
opt =  getopt(argc, argv, optString);  //  defined as optString = "qmc";

while (opt != -1) {
    printf (opt);
    switch (opt) {
    //prevents program from printing to a file
    case 'q':
        tofile = 1;
        break;
    // max size of the prime numbers
    case 'm':
        maxPrime = atoi(optarg);
        break;

    case 'c':
        numProcs = atoi(optarg);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm tried to figure out what is going on, but I cannot see why argc and argv are not getting values.  I have used this exact same parsing code before and it has worked perfectly.  Usually segmentation faults are pretty easy (accessing memory locations you shouldn't be), but there is no reason I shouldn't have access to my command line arguments.

Comment: err...why do you printf argv and argc directly?

Comment: Turn on some warnings... if you haven't included `stdio.h` you should get a warning about that, and if you have, then you should have got a warning about passing a `char **` and an `int` to `printf` where a `char *` is required.

Comment: printing them to test

Comment: You should at least pretend to read the documentation. You're misusing printf and getopt in trivial ways that indicate severe cluelessness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about how to use `printf`.  What you're currently doing is a big no-no:

```
printf(argv);
printf(argc);
```

The function expects a `const char*` string that specifies the format of the output and optional variable argument list.  You are passing a double-pointer, which is not a string, and an integer, which is not even a pointer!

You want something like this:

```
printf( "Number of arguments: %d\n", argc );
for( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) {
    printf( "Arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i] );
}
```

Read up on `printf` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Okay, that confirms I have command line arguments.  However this line is causing the segmentation fault:
opt =  getopt(argc, argv, optString);   I was only using printf to see where the code was failing.

Comment: You're doing the dodgey `printf` again in the loop.  That'll be crashing too.  Also, it's potentially an infinite loop.  You should use `while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optString)) != -1)`

Comment: I have changed the code to migrate that code into the while loop condition, but I succeed in one loop before getting a seg fault.

Comment: You haven't specified in your `optString` that the `-m` and `-c` arguments take a value.  You need to use `"qm:c:"` (otherwise `optarg` might not be valid).  Read the [man-page for `getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)